# Replace \r\n for \n in CSV Writer

Tags: python, csv, python-2.7, python-2.6

I am currently opening and writing a CSV file like this in python:

```
with open('Data.csv', 'wb') as redata_csv:
    csv_writer = csv.writer(redata_csv, delimiter=',')
```

however, each new line ends with `\r\n`, and I would like it to end with just `\n` instead. I can't find how...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the [`lineterminator`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.Dialect.lineterminator) keyword argument.

Both the `reader` and `writer` classes support the creation of a custom anonymous dialect via keyword arguments.  You are already doing that in part by setting `delimiter` - adding `lineterminator` gets you an anonymous dialect that is delimited by commas and is terminated by line feeds.

Comment: How could I miss that... Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

```
csv.writer(reindentified_csv, delimiter=',', lineterminator='\n')
```

---

[csv.writer Documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.writer):

> *csv.writer(csvfile, dialect='excel', **fmtparams)*
>
> ...
>
> The other optional fmtparams keyword arguments can be given to override individual formatting parameters in the current dialect.

[Dialects and Formatting Parameters](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#dialects-and-formatting-parameters):

> *lineterminator*
>
> The string used to terminate lines produced by the writer. It defaults to `'\r\n'`.